# Linux who --process option

Tags: linux, shell

I was playing around with *who* when I noticed that the *who -p* option does not give any output. Running the command as root also didn't change the output.
I tried this on a CentOS, Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 13.10.

Is the command deprecated or is it not compatible with newer init systems like upstart or systemd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the `man` page for `who`

> -p, --process
>   print active processes spawned by init"

Looks like no processes are spawned by "init"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init
[EDIT]

I did some looking into the wiki page and it turns out that

> Traditionally, one of the major drawbacks of init is that it starts
>   tasks serially, waiting for each to finish loading before moving on to
>   the next. When startup processes end up I/O blocked, this can result
>   in long delays during boot. Various efforts have been made to replace
>   the traditional init daemons to address this and other design problems

I'm guessing this might lend a hand to the reason why no processes show up when running `who -p`. Looks like `init` daemons are getting run out of town.

Comment: I just checked my processes and /sbin/init indeed doesn't spawn anything. A simple solution to my curiosity.If I recall correctly, init did indeed spawn processes with older init systems.

Comment: @cebalrai I read into the wiki page a bit and found out they aren't used much anymore, maybe that explains it. I edited the answer with what I found :)